# I want to make directory to current active theme in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a plugin wherein i want to make a /CSS/ directory in the currently activated theme.

using `get_template_directory_uri()` not working because its https:// path.
I want an Absolute directory for making dir.

Here is code i am using:

```
$directoryName = ''.get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/';
if(!is_dir($directoryName)){
  mkdir($directoryName, 0755, true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the path on the file system, you need to use:

```
get_template_directory()
```

instead of:

```
get_template_directory_uri()
```

Comment: I would suggest `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` since this would work with child themes. `get_template_directory_uri()` will always go to the parent theme.